# CSS Flex 2 div row...also stretch height

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have some css and I'm using flex.

Here is code:

```css
    .flex-container {
      display: flex;
      align-items: stretch;
      background-color: #ff0000;
    }
    
    .flex-container > div {
      background-color: DodgerBlue;
      color: white;
      margin: 10px;
      text-align: center;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="flex-container">
      <div style="flex-grow: 1">left</div>
      <div style="flex-grow: 60">auto</div>
    </div>
```

Right now it's doing what I want it to do which is that I have 2 div's of different sizes side by side.

But there's 1 more thing I need.

I need this 2 div's to also stretch in height.

How can I do that?

Comment: they are already stretched in height https://jsfiddle.net/fpvw81h9/

Comment: You set `margin` for `div` so gap between them and not getting full height is because of this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just give the container the height property then the items will automatically get stretch check the snippet below.

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100vh;
  align-items: stretch;
  background-color: #ff0000;
}

.flex-container > div {
  background-color: DodgerBlue;
  color: white;
  margin: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div style="flex-grow: 1">left</div>
  <div style="flex-grow: 60">auto</div>
</div>
```